# How to make docker reset the image on remote server?

Tags: docker

On docker build from jenkins 1st docker images are created tagged properly as `LATEST` on remote server.

On rebuild it supposed to overwrite docker image on server. But it didn't. 
Virtually it creates *new* docker images with `no-tag` repository and `no-tag` tag. And avoid using predefined domain name for image. 
So creates a new because it's supposed create NEW image because they are totally different.

Is there any way to avoid just deleting image directly from the remote server? But to update image docker on same tag(domain) name?

Any ideas on workaround? How to avoid making new docker images with static unchanged TAG name from jenkins build. 
Because it eats a lot of memory space on the moment when run on cron.

How can I overwrite docker image or make a facade that it's overwrited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete no-tag images after build image from jenkins by: `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Comment: Then I'll delete all my new docker images :) but supposed to delete old one. So the next that will come will be with latest tag.
Actually it's new to me. That from jenkins. On same tag. Each next build despite 1st throws unnamed images.

Comment: If you want to delete current image, you should type: `old_id=$(docker images | grep <image_name> | grep <image_tag> | awk '{print $3}'); <build image steps> && docker rmi $old_id`